# Offline SQL Storage/Sync - Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, offline

I have recently created a Web Application with Ruby on Rails using a postgresql database, which operates similar to a blog, allowing logged in users to create specific article posts. 
However, the next step is to Create some form of offline storage, so that a user could create numerous articles while offline, and when they gain internet access, it sync the data up. 
Not too sure how to go about doing this. My client has stated "Offline storage to store all content if user offline"
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the RailsCasts episode [247](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1) and [248](http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2) about Offline Apps.

Comment: I will give this a look @tauhidul35 Unfortunately I am at work now so can't state whether it will solve the issues, I will update when I get home and give it a go